# How to find maximum values of specific data type in list of tuples and update dictionary with these values?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

If I have the dictionary

```
max_values = {
    'int': 0,
    'float': 0
}
```

and I have such a list of tuples

```
mylist = [(1, 'int'), (3, 'int'), (2, 'float'), (4, 'float')]
```

How can I find the maximum value of the specific data_type and update the dictionary values?

The dictionary should be

```
max_values = {
    'int': 3,
    'float': 4
}
```

How to find maximum values and create new list?

```
new_list = [(3, 'int'), (4, 'float')]
```

Comment: have you tried anything *at all*? Sees pretty straightforward

Answer (score 1):

```
for value, data_type in mylist:
    max_values[data_type] = max(value, max_values[data_type])
```

Comment: Thank you! It solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

[pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) is great for this especially if you have a large dataset:

```
import pandas as pd

mylist = [(1, 'int'), (3, 'int'), (2, 'float'), (4, 'float')]

a = pd.DataFrame(mylist).groupby(1).max().to_dict()[0]
```

Or you can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

get_val, get_type = map(itemgetter, (0, 1))
max_values = {k: max(map(get_val, g)) for k, g in groupby(mylist, get_type)}
```

I used `operator.itemgetter` as it's more efficient than a lambda expression.

Note: You will need to sort `mylist` using `sorted(mylist, key=get_type)` if the list isn't sorted by type already

Comment: Thank you. I don't have large dataset, but will have this solution in mind.

Comment: @vaprelko see my edit to include `itertools`

Answer (score 0):

You can first generate the dictionary with checking the maximum value of key for each type . Then using list comprehension you can generate the new list as shown below.

```
for key, typ in mylist:
    if key > max_values[typ]:
        max_values[typ] = key
print(max_values)
new_list = [(x,y) for y,x in list(max_values.items())]
print(new_list)
```

This will give outputs for dictionary and list as below.

```
{'int': 3, 'float': 4}
[(3, 'int'), (4, 'float')]
```

Comment: Thank you! It helped a lot!

Comment: No problem glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

It can be a one liner:

```
new_list = [max(mylist, key=lambda item: item[0] if item[1]==tp else 0) for tp in {v for k, v in mylist}]
```

You can find the types by creating a set

```
types = {v for _, v in mylist}
# {'int', 'float'}
```

you can find only the elements with a specific type by:

```
int_vals = [(val, tp) for val, tp in mylist if tp == 'int']
```

and you can find the max of the list above by telling max that you're interested in the max of the `val` part:

```
max(int_vals, key=lambda item: item[0])
```

you can combine the last two steps with:

```
max_int_val = max(mylist, key=lambda item: item[0] if item[1] == 'int')
```

and then you just need to iterate over the types to create the new list

```
new_list = []
for tp in types:
    new_list.append(max(mylist key=lambda item: item[0] if item[1] == tp)
```

which is an expanded version of the one-liner at the top.

If you also need the `max_values` dict, you can get it by:

```
max_values = {v: k for k, v in new_list}
```